# Create array containing first element of each struct in an array in a Spark dataframe field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I go from an array of structs to an array of the first element of each struct, within a PySpark dataframe?

An example will make this clearer. Let's say I have the dataframe defined as follows:

```
scoresheet = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", [("Math",100),("English",80)]),("Bob", [("Math", 90)]),("Charlie", [])],["name","scores"])
```

The schema and the dataframe defined by the above look as follows:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = true)

+-------+--------------------------+
|name   |scores                    |
+-------+--------------------------+
|Alice  |[[Math,100], [English,80]]|
|Bob    |[[Math,90]]               |
|Charlie|[]                        |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

You can see that the subjectwise marks are contained in an ordered struct of type `(Subject,Marks)` for each student. The number of subjects for each student is not constant and may be zero.

I'd like to go from this to producing a new dataframe which only contains the subjects in an array for each student, without the marks. It should produce an empty array for students with no subjects. In short, it should look like this:

```
+-------+---------------+
|name   |scores         |
+-------+---------------+
|Alice  |[Math, English]|
|Bob    |[Math]         |
|Charlie|[]             |
+-------+---------------+
```

Note that the number of rows is the same as before; so I can't use explode for this unless I regroup afterwards, which seems computationally inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best you can do is udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

take_first = udf(lambda rows: [row[0] for row in rows], ArrayType(StringType()))

scoresheet.withColumn("scores", take_first("scores"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the expected result:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

scoresheet.select(F.col("scores._1").alias("subject"))
```

The output is:

```
+-------+----------------------------+---------------+
|name   |scores                      |subject        |
+-------+----------------------------+---------------+
|Alice  |[[Math, 100], [English, 80]]|[Math, English]|
|Bob    |[[Math, 90]]                |[Math]         |
|Charlie|[]                          |[]             |
+-------+----------------------------+---------------+
```

---

The `_1` is the struct field name of array elements, as shown by scoresheet schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = true)
```

As general rule `.select("<column_name>.<field_name>")` extracts field from a struct or from an array of structs.

---

As schema was not provided on DataFrame construction, fields in `scores` column got autogenerated names `_1` and `_2`. To improve readability, you can specify them as `subject` and `mark` and then access them with `scores.subject` and `scores.mark`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


scoresheet = spark.createDataFrame([
        ("Alice", [("Math", 100), ("English", 80)]),
        ("Bob", [("Math", 90)]),
        ("Charlie", []),
    ],
    schema=T.StructType([
        T.StructField("name", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("scores", T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
                T.StructField(name="subject", dataType=T.StringType()),
                T.StructField(name="mark", dataType=T.IntegerType()),
        ])))
    ]),
)
scoresheet.select("scores.subject")
```

Comment: While the other answers still work (and maybe were the only way back when they were contributed?), this is much simpler and more efficient. It should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here is the version with explode, group-by, and aggregate.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

scoresheet.select('name').join(
    scoresheet
    .withColumn('score', f.explode('scores'))
    .withColumn('subject', f.col('score').getField('_1'))
    .groupBy('name')
    .agg(f.collect_list('subject').alias('subjects'))
    , on='name'
    , how='left'
)
```

Since this is purely in PySpark, I wouldn't be surprised if this were faster than the UDF version in some circumstances, but I haven't done any profiling. The left join is to make sure students with no results aren't dropped in the final results.